# jQuery if class name contains

Tags: jquery, jconsole

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="item">Item #SKU987</div>
```

I'm trying to create a simple jQuery, but it keeps on returning `undefined`

```
    if (jQuery('div.item:contains("Item #SKU987")').length) {
alert("Hello! This works!");
}
```

I'm trying this out in the console and I keep on getting `undefined`

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this executed after this **DOM element is loaded** and **jQuery is loaded**? Are there any errors in console log? Also, it is a good idea to use `text()` and JS conditions instead of `:contains` selector if applicable.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes, it's executed after DOM element and jQuery is loaded

Comment: @Haim Have you looked at my 2 solutions?

Comment: @Haim when you type `jQuery` in console, what are you getting ?

Comment: `function (a,b){return new m.fn.init(a,b)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using $(document).ready(function(){....}). Here's a solution. Hope it helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     if (jQuery('div.item:contains("Item #SKU987")').length) {
     alert("Hello! This works!");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">Item #SKU987</div>
```

**Here's another solution:**

```js
if($(".item").text().indexOf("Item #SKU987") !== -1){
  alert("Hello! This works!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">Item #SKU987</div>
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` as a reminder, I'm trying this in the console

Comment: @Haim I dont get any errors at all. You are checking if the string "Item #SKU987" belongs to the class item correct?

Comment: @Haim does it say in which line you are getting the error when you use my code?

Comment: Ijust get plain undefined - i'm a newbie with the console so I might be doing something obviously wrong

Answer (score 2):

See @HenryDev's second solution.
If you run it in the console you will get `undefined` as result because this the if statement doesn't have value itself. Just ignore this result in the console.
When using `indexOf` you must be aware of the case of the letters. Are you sure the text you are looking for is in the exact case and not lower or upper case?
Use `view-source:` to be sure you are searching for the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if( jQuery('.item').eq(0).html() == "Item #SKU987" ) {
     alert('it finally worked!');
}
```

Alternatively if you have multiple `.items`, use this:

```
jQuery.each('.item', function(i,v) {
    if( jQuery(this).html() == "Item #SKU987"; )
        alert('index: '+i+' contains "Item #SKU987"');
});
```

**[jsfiddle](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html)**

Comment: Can you post the error...which line? How many elements are present that have `.item`? There might be error with your code... Have you verified your html? You can validate your html by [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html) link. @Haim

Comment: my HTML is valid - there's only one class called item

Comment: can you share a link for me @Haim or jsfiddle will also work fine if you are in a localhost. Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/aniketsahrawat/uhe6jxmy/) fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
if ($(".item").text() == "Item #SKU987") {
alert("Hello! This works!");
}
```

Comment: still getting `undefined`

Comment: this means your js did not find your html element

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside `$(document).ready();`. Then it will work. I have attached the sample code. Your issue was that your dom has not loaded when you called the selector.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   if (jQuery('div.item:contains("Item #SKU987")').length) {
    alert("Hello! This works!");
   }
  });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="item">Item #SKU987</div>
 </body>

</html>
```